# How to send any Object to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service and application. My application occasionally sends some text messages (string[]) to the WCF service, which then parses it.

Now I would like my application to send objects of class `MyObject` to WCF service. Then the service should have chance also parse (I mean it should has chance to deserialize its data (e.g. `myObjectInstance.name`, etc.))

How to implement that?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Well, instead of a `string`, just define a parameter of `MyObject` datatype in your service contract, and that's all there is! Now re-create your client-side proxy, and when calling the service, don't send a string, but instead send an object of type `MyObject`

Comment: but implementation of myobject is on my application side. How does wcf can know that this class exists.

Comment: If you use your `MyObject` in your WCF service, then you'll have to reference that assembly it's in on your server side. From that point on, WCF only cares about what your class looks like when serialized to XML on the wire. The client side will use that "footprint" on the wire to re-create your class on the client-side

Comment: @santBart wcf service have to know about MyObject because it will try to deserialize it from the client stream. If you want to pass any unknown object - just pass xml or json serialized object (as string input parameter). Then you can parse it on the service side without having object metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your code into (at least) three assemblies:

- 'Metadata' — contains `MyObject` and `IMyService` (which is your service's contract); **may not** reference any assembly that cannot be deployed at client-side
- 'Server' — implements `IMyService` and exposes the WCF service; **references 'Metadata'**
- 'Client' — contains the code of the client; **reference 'Metadata'**

That way you can easily share the 'Metadata' assembly between server and clients. Then it's just a matter of using `MyObject` as the type of any parameters of any methods in `IMyService` as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you should use [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Take a look on the following [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598157/Message-based-web-service-in-WCF)

As a result, you code could look like

```
private static void Main()
{
    var createRequest = new CreateClientRequest
        {
            Email = "emial@emial.com"
        };
    var response = SoapServiceClient.Post<CreateClientRequest, ClientResponse>(createRequest);
    Console.WriteLine("POST: {0}", response);

    var updateRequest = new UpdateClientRequest
        {
            Email = "new@email.com",
            Id = response.Id
        };
   response = SoapServiceClient.Put<UpdateClientRequest, ClientResponse>(updateRequest);
   Console.WriteLine("PUT: {0}", response);

    var getClient = new GetClientRequest
        {
            Id = response.Id
        };
   response = SoapServiceClient.Get<GetClientRequest, ClientResponse>(getClient);
    Console.WriteLine("GET: {0}", response);

    var deleteRequest = new DeleteClientRequest
        {
            Id = response.Id
        };
    SoapServiceClient.Delete(deleteRequest);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

with simple ServiceContract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISoapService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = ServiceMetadata.Operations.Process,
        ReplyAction = ServiceMetadata.Operations.ProcessResonse)]
    Message Process(Message message);

    [OperationContract(Action = ServiceMetadata.Operations.ProcessWithoutResonse)]
    void ProcessWithoutResonse(Message message);
}
```